# MS Excel passing ranging in search function

Tags: excel, function, search

Can anybody explain why this works,

=LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($O$2:$O$5,J6),$O$2:$O$4)

this looks up a value in a cell from a range of cells, works as intended.

But the search(O2:O5,J6) does not work on its own?
so, SEARCH($O$2:$O$5,J6) returs #value err. I would think that this would return the position if found. If I pass in {""}, e.g. Search({"xyz","zyx","xsy"},J6) this works and makes sense but why doesn't a range work.

an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got `Search()` backwards. Try `=LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(J6,$O$2:$O$5),$O$2:$O$4)`

Comment: I'm trying to supply a range of values to lookup in the string in the cell.

Comment: It will not work by itself because it returns an array of cells not values.  It finds every cell in O2:O5 that has a value in J6, then returns that array of cells to the LOOKUP, which then finds the last cells relative position to find the cell in the third argument.

Comment: Ah, sorry totally missed that. Interesting question!

Comment: On another note the second search you use searches a range of values and will return only the first that satisfies the criteria.  So if your array was {"x","y","z"} and J6 was "xyz".  It would only return 1.  And if J6 was "yz" then it would return an error

Comment: I thought so, needed confirmation, I couldn't find documentation on it but when I use the evaluate formula feature in excel it changes the range to {"","",""}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is two-fold.

Firstly, most functions won't accept multiple values for a single argument.  Getting them to do so requires that they be calculated as *array* formulas.  You can force a function to do this manually by confirming it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> (instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).  You'll know it's entered as an array formula because curly braces {} will surround the formula in the formula bar.  Once you've done that, go to the Formulas Tab -> Evaluate Formula to see the steps.  With just the Search function, you'll probably get something like `{#N/A!;#N/A!;11;#N/A!;#N/A!;}`. Notice that it is an array (a list) of results from the formula, with most being errors (because  the text wasn't found) and one with a proper result.

This brings us to the second part of the answer, the error-handling.  Again, most functions don't handle errors well.  If any part of a function errors, the whole function results in that error.  You can get around this with error handling functions like `ISNUMBER` or `IFERROR`.

So now that we know that, why does `LOOKUP` work?  Because it handles both cases as part of its built-in functionality.  Lookup, as part of its built-in functionality because of the specifics of how it works, evaluates its arguments as arrays This means that if you feed it *another function* as an argument (like `SEARCH` for example), it will force that function to be evaluated as an array..  A few other functions also do this, like `SUMPRODUCT` and `INDEX`.

Secondly, `LOOKUP` already has built-in error handling.  If there are errors within its arguments, it will return the answer closest to the first argument (but still underneath it).  This is why the first argument in your provided `LOOKUP` function is `1E+100` which means `10^100` or basically a 1 followed by 100 zeroes.  Any search result found is going to be a number smaller than that, so if it finds anything, it will return that number, because everything else will result in #N/A! and LOOKUP will ignore those errors.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, where could i find documentation that would provide this type of info for other functions.

Comment: A great resource for detailed information about Excel function is support.office.com and basically if a function has either an Array from (like the Lookup function does) or takes an argument of type Array (which is expanded upon in the array form of the Lookup function), it will have similar functionality.  Link for Lookup function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb